Using the "in" operator in a request to an API
One of the BestBuy API endpoints is:
https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products

Their guide here (see the very last line) says that to avoid the rate limit, one can get data for multiple skus (products) in a single call like this:
https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products(sku in(43900,2088495,7150065))?apiKey=YourAPIKey

This works. But how can I use the in operator in a similar fashion but for some of the other API end points like this one:
https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products/{sku here}/viewedUltimatelyBought?apiKey=YourAPIKey

The above works fine with a single sku such as 1542658 like this:
https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products/1542658/viewedUltimatelyBought?apiKey=YourAPIKey

But to get the data for multiple skus in one call, I tried variations of the query like these and all return error saying that the query is not valid:
https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products/(sku in(6559245, 6559246, 6559247))/viewedUltimatelyBought?apiKey=YourAPIKey

https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products/[6559245, 6559246, 6559247]/viewedUltimatelyBought?apiKey=YourAPIKey

https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products/(6559245, 6559246, 6559247)/viewedUltimatelyBought?apiKey=YourAPIKey

Can someone construct the query correctly for me? I know it may be a bit challenging without having access to the API (obviously I can't share my API key here) but I thought there may be a common format for requests like this that I am not aware of. If it matters, I use the following code to get the response to the queries:
json_content = json.loads(requests.get(query).content)


They have an example in the swagger you linked
Open Box Single SKU
https://api.bestbuy.com/beta/products/8610161/openBox?apiKey=YourAPIKey

Open Box by List of SKUs
https://api.bestbuy.com/beta/products/openBox(sku%20in(5729048,7528703,4839357,8153056,8610161))?apiKey=YourAPIKey

So your url should probably be
https://api.bestbuy.com/v1/products/viewedUltimatelyBought(sku in(6559245, 6559246, 6559247))?apiKey=YourAPIKey

Note the difference in the path between beta and v1, I'm not sure if it's important here.

I appreciate your help but that query leads to an "Error 400: bad request" using both v1 and beta
